# An object that describes the current scope

Tags: python, scope, getattr

An API I use defines a method like this:

```
def show_prop(object, propname): #...
```

What it's supposed to do is display the property on screen by calling `getattr(object, propname)` and allow the user to change the attribute, resulting in `setattr(object, propname)`.

There is no way I can change that behaviour but I want to use the API to show a local variable to the user and receive the normal feedback from the user?

I thought of a builting variable describing the current scope and the variables available, kind of like a local `__dict__` but I haven't found such thing.

```
userinput = "Default input"
show_prop(__mysterious_unknown__, 'userinput')
# Do something exciting with the changed userinput
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: There's the [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) dictionary, but you can't use `getattr` on a dictionary.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: also what is returned by `locals()` is read-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Local write access can be done only directly in the scope or in nested scopes using `nonlocal` (Python3 only).

Python doesn't have the concept of "pointer" and the only way to specify a writable place is passing a reference to the container and the "name" of the member (or the index of the array, the key of the dict).

What you can do is however create a small object on the fly just for this:

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

def foo():
    my_local = 42
    ...
    myobj = Bunch(my_local=my_local) # create the dummy instance
    show_prop(myobj, "my_local")     # call the original code
    my_local = myobj.my_local        # get modified value back
    ...
```

In Python3 would be possible to create a magic object instance that when written to the member will mutate the local on the fly (using the new Python3 `nonlocal` keyword and either a property or a `__getattr__`/`__setattr__` catch-all). I wouldn't go for this kind of strange magic unless it's really needed however...

For example:

```
def foo(obj, name):
    # the fixed API
    setattr(obj, name, 1 + getattr(obj, name))

def bar():
    myloc = 11

    # magic class...
    class MyClass:
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            # accessing any member returns the current value of the local
            return myloc
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            # writing any member will mutate the local (requires Python3)
            nonlocal myloc
            myloc = value

    foo(MyClass(), "myloc")
    print(myloc) # here myloc will have been incremented

bar()
```

Comment: This kind of "strange magic" would be much appreciated though but I guess the "class Bunch" would be good enough

Comment: @WorldSEnder: I've added an example, but don't tell anyone I told you this ;-)